# how to make a search bar for tags and usernames that filters on typing on xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to make a search bar similar to instagram or vine, as to where it filters the results as you type.I also want to know the code on how to change from username to tag buttons  under the search bar. How do I make one? I'm also using Xcode 4.6.

Comment: What does GIT stand for, in your sentence?

Comment: @Jubobs a GIT is source code management (SCM)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "*Is there a GIT or source code that I can use to make on one?*"

Comment: @Jubobs i meant like a an exterior project that has the search bar code like from the ones from GITHub. sorry if I used it in the wrong context

Comment: You need to update your Xcode, 4.6 is way too old

Comment: @Jubobs I'm 14 and new, i didn't know

Comment: @Ty_ I cant, I have a white macbook that can only download xcode 4.6.3  Apple stopped making OS X for the white macbook

Comment: Also the buttons under the search bar you mentioned in you question is called a UISegmentedControl. There are a lot of tutorials about it in google.

Comment: @Ty_ Thank you so much! I was struggling for three days with this, Thank you!

Comment: @anika That's fine. You can always edit your question for clarification, you know.

Comment: This question is still Too Broad unfortunately.

Comment: @JasonMArcher do you have any suggestions on how to refrase the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're a starter I suggest you go through this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/) and other tutorials you can find from [google](http://www.google.com). This tutorial will teach you how to use the searchBar and its delegates and also filters the results as you typed.

I don't suggest you to find projects on Github, because codes their will be way too advanced and you will learn nothing from it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set up an IBAction for Editing Changed on your textfield.

You can access the text field as a parameter of the function and get the values the user typed in.